# How to check the mocked object for null condition in JUnit 5?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

If I have an object as below in service layer

```
@Autowired
private Config appConfig;
.
.
.
if(appConfig == null)
    //check configuration
```

JUnit written by mocking the object.

```
@Mock
private Config appConfig;
```

How to make that object to null in JUnit to cover that condition in test case?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. An Autowired field can never be null in Spring. So why test it?

Comment: In my application the the configuration file load manually so if the file is not in the correct place the null will arise to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
@Mock
private Config appConfig;


@Test
public void nullTest(){
 appConfig = Mockito.nullable(Config.class);
 System.out.println(appConfig == null ? "null" : "notNull");
  ..
}
```

This displays `null` as output.

Comment: Facing "UnfinishedStubbingException"

Comment: how you are using it? can you please show that

Comment: using this line directly

doAnswer(RETURNS_SMART_NULLS).when(appConfig);

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.....(ServiceTest.java:157)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn'

Comment: @SaravanakumarArunachalam, I just edited my code to fix , please check if it works for you.

Comment: You are using the appConfig in direct way. But the null check is in the service class and mock has to be done in JUnit class. In direct way it will work but it will not work when if(appConfig == null)

Comment: @SaravanakumarArunachalam , I am not sure if I am understanding your above comment properly, answers are given based on what is being understood. Update your question to specify what is exact need

Answer (score 0):

For `null` you don't need a mock at all. Why don't you just pass in the `null` value into the method to test, instead of your `appConfig` field?

Comment: That is not direct method with that parameter. That is the configuration automatically taken from class path. So i can't directly validate as you said.

Comment: Then please describe your test setup more detailed (in the question).